# redirect to another page on webform submit using [current-page:query:?] token

Tags: webforms, tokens

I am trying to configure a webform to redirect to another page after submission by including the redirect location in the url:

http://mysite/content/barb?destination=content/discus

According to webform there is a token `[current-page:query:?]` which I assume can extract the value of destination.  I have including it in the webform redirect to custom URL of the form, but I cant get it to work.

I have tried:

- [current-page:query:?]
- [current-page:query:?destination]
- [current-page:query:destination]

But nothing seems to work. What is the correct way of using this token to get a variable from the URL?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that no token is required for this...

You can select *Confirmation page* as the redirect location, then the `?destination=` parameter will just work. Not sure that this is a documented feature, though.

See also https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/120466/webform-redirect-to-referring-page-on-submit-not-showing-message which highlights a downside to this method.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the `[current-page:query:destination]` token in the *Custom URL* box, and that works too.

No problems with the confirmation message appearing, either!