# Webform Confirmation settings on form submission not working

Tags: webforms, configuration, tokens

I am using Acquia site studio components for web pages. In all the pages I have a pop-up with a webform submit button to enter to the site.

In Webform confirmation settings I have selected the option - **URL (redirects to a custom path or URL)** and in the confirmation URL textfield **[current-page:url]?[current-page:query]** is given.

On form submission, it is expected to redirect to the current page with the current query given in the URL. But, it is redirecting to previously used query parameter of the current page.

Application is using Varnish and core internal cache. I am not sure the **[current-page:url]?[current-page:query]** is getting cached.

***Steps:***
Webform will be loaded in a modal while accessing the url http://localhost/products?key=111 on click on submit button the expected result is to land on the same page with the same query parameter but, it is redirecting to http://localhost/products?key=222 where the key=222 ]

Any suggestions/alternate solution would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This still may be correct: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158003/redirect-to-another-page-on-webform-submit-using-current-pagequery-token

Comment: Thank you for the link But that didnt worked